# Bootstrap tool tip - setting different widths for different tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set different widths for different tooltips. I have a tooltip on hyper link and a tooltip on h1 element. For hyperlink i have large text so I need the width of the tool tip to be large but for h1 element default width is fine.

When I am trying to overwrite the css as below all the tool tips are getting affected. Is there a way to give the width of a tooltip inline to the element on which the tooltip is applied

```
.tooltip-inner {
   max-width: 350px;
   width: 350px;
}
```

I tried to add two separate tooltip inner styles in the css as a.tooltip-inner and h1.tooltip-inner with different widths but its not taking effect

JSFiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/vinaybvk/qr1cbu92/

Is there any other way to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(This Answer applies to BS 3.2)
The only way I can think of achieving this is by overriding the default template for the tooltip. Then you use different selectors for large and regular tooltips like so;

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uyo0tf7r/2/)

```
$('.tt_reg').tooltip();

$('.tt_large').tooltip({
    template: '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner large"></div></div>'
});
```

Note I've added the class **large** to the tooltip-inner element. You can then use css to adjust this size;

```
.large.tooltip-inner {
    width: 350px;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, there's no need to use `max-width` and `width` together.

Comment: Thanks Novocaine that solved the issue, I was trying to overwrite class and thinking that is the last level :) you went another level below by overwriting the template and adding a new class to that, good to know that we can even do in this way. Thanks once again....

Comment: Yeah at first I was hoping it was possible to overwrite just a class, but couldn't find anything built in that would allow it. Glad I could help.

Comment: This works thanks. I replaced tooltip-arrow with arrow to make the arrow appear on my bootstrap.

Answer (score 5):

Give the container div a class:

```
<div class="large-tooltip">
    <i class="icon ion-help-circled" rel="tooltip" title="Hint"></i>
</div>
```

---

```
.large-tooltip .tooltip-inner {
    width: 250px;
}
```

In order to give different widths for tool-tips, rather than from adding different templates, it is possible to add different css classes for the container element and we can change the width of each element accordingly.

Comment: This answer is lacking information (a descriptional part)

Comment: Hey, why not adding this text to your answer? It would improve it's quality enormously!

Comment: Best answer ! PURE CSS !

Answer (score 0):

The error lays in the fact that you are using the same selector for the tooltip. You need to use different selector and apply the settings on them:

In the following JSFiddle I changed the class of the second item to `example2` and I added the setting for that selector in the JS code.

HTML :

```
<div>
    <h1 rel="tooltip" title="This is Normal tooltip" class="example">Tooltip1 with normal width </h1>
    <a href="#" class="example2" rel="tooltip" title="Tool tip with large text Tool tip with large text  Tool tip with large text Tool tip with large text Tool tip with large text Tool tip with large text >Tooltip 2 with larger width</a>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$('.example').tooltip();
$('.example2').tooltip({animation:false});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qr1cbu92/2/

To change the dimension of the tooltip please refer to : [How do you change the width and height of Twitter Bootstrap's tooltips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596743/how-do-you-change-the-width-and-height-of-twitter-bootstraps-tooltips)

Comment: Those tooltips are the same size. That's not what the OP was after

Comment: @Novocaine, the OP had to different error I explain the primary error of selecting the right element. But your comment was valid Thus I added the linked to an answer on that question.

Comment: Hi David Laberge thanks for the reply, but the width is remaining same. I tried to intialize separately thinking I can give the width in the options but there is no width option. What I am trying to achieve is having different width's for different tooltips on a page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, however `.tooltip-inner{width}` for my task failed to do the job right. As for other (i.e. shorter) tooltips fixed width was too big. I was lazy to write separate html templates/classes for zilions of tooltips, so I just replaced all spaces between words with **`&nbsp;`** in each text line.