# In Bootstrap, how do I get individual tooltips to not wrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3sxez0v8/

At the moment, both tooltips wrap.

I can get both tooltips to wrap by following:

[How do you change the width and height of Twitter Bootstrap's tooltips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596743/how-do-you-change-the-width-and-height-of-twitter-bootstraps-tooltips)

```
.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 350px;
    width: 350px; 
}
```

but this causes both tooltips not to wrap.

How do I get just the first tooltip not to wrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use template in options to apply different html content with different classes for wrap and nowrap like below:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({template:'<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'})
})

$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip-nowrap"]').tooltip({template:'<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner nowrap"></div></div>'})
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9k3Lbtr6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap allows you to render your tooltip with rich HTML content by leveraging the `html:` option.  As such, you can replace normal whitespace characters with non-breaking white-space characters to force content not to wrap.

You *could* leverage jQuery's `$.each()` function and a simple regex `.replace()` to automate this process.  Add classes on the button to determine when to apply the forced *one line*.  You will have to make the window narrow (horizontally) to see the effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/vqgj8brs/1/

```
.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 500px !important;
}

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 ">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default one-line" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="This is a longer tooltip which SHOULD NOT wrap" data-container="body">Tooltip No Wrap</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="This is a longer tooltip which SHOULD wrap" data-container="body">Tooltip top 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></div>
</div>

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').each(function(index, element) {
  var title_text = $(element).data('original-title');
  var convert_white_space = title_text.replace(/ /g, '&#160;');

  if ($(element).hasClass('one-line')) {
    $(element).attr('data-original-title', convert_white_space);
    $(element).tooltip({
      html: true,
      placement: "bottom"
    });
    console.log(convert_white_space);
  } else {
    $(element).tooltip({
      html: true,
      placement: "bottom"
    });
  }
});
```