# how to customize tooltip width in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have a bootstrap tooltip like the following.

```html
<i class="fas fa-question-circle" style="color: #f44336; cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-container="body" title="" data-original-title="some text: just a test text just a test text. <br> Submitted: just a test text"></i>
```

[image]

My Question is, I want to resize the width of this tooltip. My aim is to make the first sentence in one line. is there any possible solution for this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you change the width and height of Twitter Bootstrap's tooltips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596743/how-do-you-change-the-width-and-height-of-twitter-bootstraps-tooltips)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have goog informations :
https://www.jquery-az.com/bootstrap-tooltip-simple-and-customized-tooltips-demos/